# Scala-IDE 3.0: 2.9.2 -> 2.10.0

Tags: eclipse, scala, scala-ide

I installed scala-IDE 3.0 on my Linux VM and after the installation the new version converted all my scala projects to 2.10.0.  How do I manage the scala version from eclipse on a project by project basis.  scala-IDE 3.0 is claimed to be both 2.9.2 and 2.10.0 compatible though through different update sites:

> 3.0.0 Release
>
> This release is available for both Scala 2.9 and Scala 2.10, and both Eclipse 3.7 (Indigo) and Eclipse 3.8/4.2 (Juno), through different update sites.

Comment: From my understanding you won't be able to have different projects in the same workspace use different versions of scala via the scala IDE.  I think if you want to do this you need two separate installs of eclipse each with different versions of the plugin installed.

Comment: @cmbaxter is right. +1 from me!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

At the moment (May 23, 2013), you can only have one Scala IDE plug-in per Eclipse intallation. Hence, if some of your projects are on Scala 2.9, while others are on Scala 2.10, you will need to use two different Eclipse installations, with the right Scala IDE plug-in installed.

We are aware that this isn't ideal, and we are actively working to remove this limitation.

The best workaround I can offer you at the moment is to use the [pre-packaged Scala IDE SDK](http://scala-ide.org/download/sdk.html), which is available for both Scala 2.9 and Scala 2.10. This way you don't have to waste time setting up Eclipse for Scala development.