# how to use a different version of scala library with scala ide 3.0.2?

Tags: scala, ide, scala-2.10, scala-2.9

I've got the newest Scala IDE (3.0.2) and I want to compile my stuff with Scala 2.9.3.  I've added that version of Scala as a Maven dependency and removed the default 2.10.0 that the IDE bundles with the new project (not my system Scala version, by the way!).  The IDE then tells me Scala is not on the build path, even when I add in the jars to the build path.  When I try to add a "Scala Library" through that dialogue, it doesn't give me any options and adds 2.10.0.  I've gone through the project settings, and would have expected to see a "Scala version" option, but there isn't (only a "Java version" option.)

My question is this:

How do I add a different version of Scala as the Scala library in Scala IDE 3.0.2 ?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I asked a similar question a while back. Short answer is, you can't.

My post: 
[Scala-IDE 3.0: 2.9.2 -> 2.10.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16702140/scala-ide-3-0-2-9-2-2-10-0)